# Extracting Free Format Argument Options using Regex

Tags: regex, string, arguments

I have argument string that contains options for a compiler/assembler, for example

```
-f bin -o filename.exe -l test.lst or
-fbin -ofilename.exe -l test.lst
```

My basic regex skills allow me to detect -ofilename.exe in the second argument list (for example

```
 (-o\w+.\w+)
```

but I am struggling to come up with an expression that can capture the -o flag and filename for **both** strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to look for possible whitespace between the `-o` option and the filename.

```
(-o\s*\w+\.\w+)
```

**Note:** You should properly escape the dot `.` to specify you want to match a literal character.

Since the filename is separated by whitespace, you could simplify your regex as follows:

```
(-o\s*\S+)
```

Comment: Thanks for the insight into the first option, but the real solution is the in the simplified expression you provided.  Thanks again